# Правильно написание кода

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS, часто наблюдаю, как все более-менее опытные дядьки твердят, что функция должна выполнять только одно действие, ибо в противном случае - говнокод.

То есть, если есть некая функция `checkPermission` то она должна только проверять разрешение и возвращать true/false, но никак не выводить на экран с сообщением.

Собственно, вот мой код:

```
let access = true;

function checkPermission(access) {
    if(access) alert("access true");
    else alert("access denied!");
}

checkPermission(access);
```

Следуя Библии всея кодинга, так делать ниок. Извольте отредактировать мой код как положено и пояснить, почему и как надо делать.

Comment: Ну alert тоже функция, так что не знаю что вам не нравится. Может пример не совсем удачный, здесь без функции легко обойтись например: let access=true; alert(\`access ${access&&'true'||'denied'}\`);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классическом виде код можно представить так:

```
let access = true;

function checkPermission(access){
    return !!access;
}

function alertPermission(access) {
    let permission = checkPermission(access);
    alert("access " + permission);
}

alertPermission(access);
```

Comment: не правильно, у вас `alertPermission` вызывает проверку доступности, хотя должен только выводить результат)))

Comment: тогда нужно было написать `alertPermission(checkPermission(access));`

Comment: _Не надо вызовы функций комбинировать_ про функциональное программирование не слышали?)))

Comment: Вы не могли бы пояснить, чем этот код лучше представлвенного автором.